# Paypal Sandbox Do Direct Payment Internal Error 10001 Timeout Processing Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is in an MVC2 project, so I'm using C# in ASP.
This is what I'm sending to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp:

```
VERSION = 65.0
SIGNATURE = AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AxdW2pQp.tWHTjGNcHflR-LJhJ0t
USER = seller_1283487740_biz_api1.gmail.com
PWD = 1283487748
AMOUNT = 50.00
CREDITCARDTYPE = Visa
ACCT = 4031477440127509
EXPDATE = 12/2015
CVV2 =123
IPADDRESS = 127.0.0.1
METHOD = DoDirectPayment
```

I can GetBalance, I can produce other errors when I intentionally send something wrong, but DoDirectPayment or DoAuthorization returns this:

```
TIMESTAMP = 2010-12-24T03:35:10Z
CORRELATIONID = 2ca329fdbe3c0
ACK = Failure
L_ERRORCODE0 = 10001
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 = Internal Error
L_LONGMESSAGE0 = Timeout processing request
```

Why Am I getting this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, I'm getting the same thing.  I tested my code on their production URL and it worked just fine.

Given how much they are focused on developers, it's amazing how horrible their API is.  I can get points and follow other people on their little social network, x.com, but I CAN'T TELL WHAT THE CURRENT VERSION OF THE API IS!?!  (You have to view the source of the webpage and find it embedded in an HTML comment)  `</rant>`

Comment: I eventually got it worked out with Paypal, and found out there IS a bug with their sandbox environment.  It only makes working accounts with Payments Pro activated properly about a third of the time.  Paypal support worked with me, and we simply kept making new accounts until we got one that worked.  I could go into a rant as well about how messed up of a solution that is, but I was just happy to get it working.

Comment: Thanks Adam, was tearing out my hair trying to get it working on the sandbox. Also, I can't believe stuff like this is still an issue.

Answer (score 6):

From what I've read around, this can be a sign of malformed data.  In my case, I was sending the form as

```
multipart/form-data
```

instead of

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I hadn't read anywhere in the docs about form encoding, but as soon as I changed it the PP server got a lot more friendly.

Comment: yeah here the same, with multipart/form-data i had "10001 - Internal server error" as response from paypal, but as soon i switched to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it was ACK = Success :)

Comment: I was having this problem w/ MassPay, and this was the solution that resolved my problem (however it gave way to ```The%20user%20account%20needs%20to%20have%20its%20sending%20limit%20removed%20in%20order%20to%20make%20a%20mass%20payment%2e```)

Comment: Thanks! This finally did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its Pay Pals defence againest attacks. Theres certain procedures that action in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Error codes:
* 100 Access denied
* 105 Order already exists
* 106 DID ID: DID_ID NOT found
* 107 Invalid Protocol
* 108 DID: DIDNUMBER NOT found
* 109 DID: DIDNUMBER in Pending/Remove status
* 110 DID: DIDNUMBER NOT renewed
* 111 Invalid status code. Valid codes: 0 - Disable, 1 - Enable
* 113 Order NOT found for DIDNUMBER
* 114 Order already canceled for DIDNUMBER
* 115 ORDER: Cannot cancel not pending order for DIDNUMBER. Please, use did_cancel 
* 120 UNIQ: UNIQUEKEY NOT found
* 121 No cities for this country
* 150 Sandbox error. DIDs max limit reached
* 200 Internal Server Error
```

Through a Sandbox control panel these error messages are given to a user if the server believes that it is under-attack.