# Integrating DoDirect Paypal API Code

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating DoDirect Paypal API Code to my website and i am getting following error.

```
DoDirectPayment failed: 
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d09%2d11T04%3a56%3a46Z 
        [CORRELATIONID] => e293002f805d 
        [ACK] => Failure     
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001 
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal%20Error 
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout%20processing%20request 
      )
```

I am using sandbox Credentials. Any error help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal Sandbox Do Direct Payment Internal Error 10001 Timeout Processing Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524059/paypal-sandbox-do-direct-payment-internal-error-10001-timeout-processing-request)